# Django template timesince filter - limit

Tags: django, templates

Is it possible to limit django timesince filter say to 7 days.
If date is more than 7 days, don't apply the filter

Comment: Can you provide the code if completed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source for `timesince` is located under [`django/django/utils/timesince.py`](http://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/timesince.py). It's short and should require no great effort, to modify it to accept another argument, if some time (e.g. 7 days) is exceeded.